# Want a count but it repeats 1 with every record

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery, inner-query

I want a count but it repeats 1 with every record. Can you please suggest what to do?

```
SELECT Count(*),
       innerTable.*
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT NAME
                FROM   tours
                WHERE  tours.id = tourbooking.tourid)         AS NAME,
               (SELECT url
                FROM   tours
                WHERE  tours.id = tourbooking.tourid)         AS Url,
               (SELECT TOP 1 NAME
                FROM   tourimages
                WHERE  tourimages.tourid = tourbooking.tourid
                ORDER  BY id ASC)                             AS ImageName,
               (SELECT duration + ' ' + CASE WHEN durationtype = 'd' THEN
                       'Day(s)' WHEN
                       durationtype =
                       'h' THEN 'Hour(s)' END
                FROM   tours
                WHERE  tours.id = tourbooking.tourid)         AS Duration,
               (SELECT Replace(Replace('<a> Adult(s) - <c> Children', '<a>', Sum
                               (CASE
                                       WHEN [type] = 1 THEN 1
                                       ELSE 0
                                END)),
                       '<c>',
                       Sum(CASE
                       WHEN [type] = 2 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                       END))
                FROM   tourperson
                WHERE  tourperson.bookingid = tourbooking.id) AS TotalPassengers
               ,
               startdate,
               createddate                                    AS BookingDate,
               id                                             AS BookingID,
               [status],
               serviceprice
        FROM   tourbooking
        WHERE  memberid = 6)AS innerTable
GROUP  BY innerTable.NAME,
          innerTable.bookingdate,
          innerTable.bookingid,
          innerTable.duration,
          innerTable.imagename,
          innerTable.serviceprice,
          innerTable.startdate,
          innerTable.status,
          innerTable.totalpassengers,
          innerTable.url
```

Comment: This is sounds like [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please give us your tables with data and what do you expect and not your approach to achieve it.

Comment: Because all your inner queries can be combined using join.

Comment: Select Count(*),T.* From (SELECT Tours.Name,Tours.Duration,Tours.DurationType,Tours.Url,TourImages.Name as ImageName,TourBooking.CreatedDate as BookingDate,
TourBooking.ID as BookingID, TourBooking.StartDate as StartDate,TourBooking.ServicePrice as ServicePrice
from TourBooking join Tours on TourBooking.TourID = Tours.ID
join TourImages on TourImages.TourID = TourBooking.TourID
 Where TourBooking.MemberID = 6) as T
 Group by 
 T.BookingDate,
t.BookingID,
t.Duration,
t.DurationType,
t.ImageName,
t.Name,
t.ServicePrice,
t.StartDate,
t.Url

Comment: @Coder of Code please check it ,, it is through join and i just want a count and result

Comment: Post your new query as update in question and did you read @Throsten answer. It explains the probable cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select records from `tourbooking`. One of the columns you select is `id`. This is probably the table's primary key and thus unique. (If not, you should hurry to change that name.)

You call this ID `BookingID`, and it is one of the columns you group by. So you get one result record per record in `tourbooking`. The number of records within such a "group" is of course 1; it is the one record you select and show.

If you built *real* groups, say a result record per *day*, then you'd get a real count, e.g. the number of bookings per day.

Comment: yes you are right you got the point ..  can you post how is that possible  ... BookingID is Primary key

Comment: In your GROUP BY clause you would specify what records you want to see in your results. An example: `GROUP BY innerTable.bookingdate, innerTable.status` would give you *one* result record *per* bookingdate and status. In your SELECT clause, you would not select `innerTable.*`, but aggregates for a group, e.g.: `innerTable.bookingdate, innerTable.status, MIN(innerTable.duration) AS min_duration, MAX(innerTable.duration) AS max_duration, SUM(innerTable.totalpassengers) AS passengers, COUNT(*) AS bookings`. So: think about what you want to group by and think about what data to show per group.

Comment: please visit this .....    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428157/how-to-get-count-with