# How to get count with *

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select Count(*),* from TourBooking Where MemberID = 6
```

Giving an error

> "Column 'TourBooking.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Select Count(*)  from TourBooking Where MemberID = 6

Comment: @HelpingHands I also want all data from table not only count

Comment: Do you want the count for `memberid = 6` or the total count of all rows in that table (regardless of your `where` clause)

Comment: Can't you just `select * .. where MemberID = 6` and then count the number of results?

Comment: Your query makes no sense - run 2 queries instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GROUP BY / aggregate function confusion in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count()` is an aggregate function and thus requires a `group by`. If you want to count the total number of rows in your result, you can use a window function to add such a column:

```
select count(*) over () as total_count, 
       TourBooking.*
from TourBooking
where MemberID = 6;
```

If you want the total count in the table `TourBooking` *regardless* of the value in the column `MemberId` you need a scalar sub-query in order to retrieve the count:

```
Select (select Count(*) from TourBooking) as total_count,
       TourBooking.*
from TourBooking 
where MemberID = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a subselect:

```
Select (select Count(*) from TourBooking Where MemberID = 6), * 
    from TourBooking 
Where MemberID = 6
```

Answer (score -2):

Please change your code from

```
Select Count(*),* from TourBooking Where MemberID = 6
```

into

```
Select Count(*) from TourBooking Where MemberID = 6
```

Comment: don't use code snippets for sql, just use 4 spaces at the start or use the code sample button `{}`